# What are the parts of speech of "tiring" and "tired" below?

Tags: parts-of-speech

- He is **tiring**
- He is already **tiring**

  (may be 2 different answers above, and below)
- He is **tired**
- He is already **tired**

Further, quoting from World Book Dictionary :-

"*a participle is a form of the verb used as an adjective or noun*",

Does that mean that a participle is a verb, or an adjective/noun?

Comment: The terms are inconsistent. _Participle_ is a term from Latin grammar; Latin had a lot of participles (many more than English) and they had special grammar. The original 8 parts of speech included Participle, and **didn't** include Adjective (they behave like nouns in Latin, so that's what the grammarians called them). In English there are two verb forms -- the _-ing_ form, called the Present  Active Participle , and the _-ed/-en_ form, called the Perfect Passive Participle. These are inflected forms of the verb, and feature in many constructions; they are frequently used as adjectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the participles in your examples are ambiguous between being verbs and adjectives. I will first explain why that is, and then I'll explain the concept of a participle.

For what it's worth: without further context, I personally would be more likely to interpret as adjectives all of them except the one in *already tiring*; that one is irredeemably ambiguous for me. Nevertheless, to repeat, **all** of them could be interpreted as either verbs or adjectives.

**Verb vs adjective**

Consider the following sentences (yours are [1] i a. and ii a. and [2] i and ii). As I will explain, *tiring* and *tired* are adjectives in iii and iv, verbs in v, and ambiguous between those two in i and ii. I will follow the discussion in various parts of [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468).

[1]   i    a. *He is tiring.*                       b. *He is dull*.                            c. *He is getting tired*
       ii   a. *He is already tiring.*         b. *He is already dull*.            c. *He is already getting tired.*
      iii   a. *He is very tiring.*               b. *He is very dull*.                  c. **He is very getting tired.*
       iv  a. *He becomes tiring.*            b. *He becomes dull*.               c. **He becomes getting tired.*
       v   a. *He is tiring as we speak.*  b.  **He is dull as we speak*.   c. *He is getting tired as we speak.*

[2]   i    *He is tired.*
       ii   *He is already tired.*
      iii   *He is very tired.*
      iv   *He becomes tired.*
       v     *He is tired as we speak.*

In [1] i a. and ii a., the ambiguity is between the verb *to tire* (in its intransitive meaning, which is *to become tired*) and the adjective *tiring* (which is applied to things that cause weariness and fatigue). For example, in the adjectival interpretation, *He is already tiring* means, roughly, 'He is already making everyone tired'. In contrast, in the verbal interpretation, it means exactly what [1] ii c. says: 'He is already getting tired'.

In [2] i and ii, the ambiguity is between the same verb, *to tire* (this time in its transitive meaning, which is *to make someone tired*) and the well-known adjective *tired*. Let's again look at ii. The adjectival interpretation is straightforward. To get the verbal meaning, it will help to attach a *by* phrase: *He is already tired by all the attention*, which is the passive voice construction whose basic counterpart is *All the attention already tires him* (we should imagine someone is giving a running commentary of what is happening, so that the present simple tense doesn't sound awkward).

In both [1] and [2], iii-v break the ambiguity by using constructions which are only compatible with adjectives (in iii and iv) or with verbs (in v).

In [1], the b. entries replace *tiring* by a word that is unambiguously an adjective, *dull*. The c. entries replace it by an unambiguously verbal expression, *getting tired*.

We see that both *He is...* and *He is already...* can work with either an adjective (in b.) or a verb (in c.).

However, only adjectives can be modified by *very* (and not even all of them, just the gradable ones). You can be *very dull*, but you can't **very enjoy it*. This is why [1] iii b. is OK, but iiii c. is not.

Thus, the ability to be modified by *very* is sufficient grounds to conclude that something is an adjective. The converse is not true, however: just because something *cannot* be modified by *very* doesn't mean it's not an adjective (e.g. you cannot have **a very federal agency* or **a very left exit*).

Another distictive propoerty of adjectives is that they can serve as predicative complements (PCs). The most common verb that takes PCs is of course ***be***, but that verb features in all kinds of other grammatical constructions where it takes verbs as complements, and it may be hard to decide whether one is looking at a PC or some other kind of complement. Luckily, there are other verbs that take PCs: *seem*, *appear*, *look*, *become*, etc. So you can *appear dull*, which is why [1] iv b. is OK, but you can't **appear getting tired*, which is why iv c. is unacceptable.

Thus, [1] iii and iv can only have adjectival interpretations, with the meaning, roughly, *he makes people very tired* (in iii) or *he seems to make people tired* (in iv).   Similarly, [2] iii and iv can only have adjectival interpretations, which probably don't need explaining.

Conversely, the adjunct *as we speak* normally cannot work with verb phrases of the form ***be*** + PC, which is why v b. is unacceptable, but it works perfectly with the present continuous tense, which is why v c. is fine. Therefore, [1] v a. only has verbal interpretation, whose meaning is precisely the same as that expressed by v c.

Similarly, [2] v only has a verbal interpretation, and again it will help to add a *by* phrase to get a better sense of its meaning: *He is tired by all the heckling as we speak*, whose active-voice counterpart is *All the heckling tires him as we speak* (we should again imagine someone is giving a running commentary of what is happening).

**The concept of participle**

From CGEL, p. 78:

> The central idea in the traditional concept of participle is that it is a word formed from a verb base which functions as or like an adjective. A second general property of participles is that these words are also used in combination with an auxiliary to form a compound tense, aspect, mood, or voice.

**The past participle**

> The adjective-like character of *written* is seen in [9].
>
> [9]  i *I came across a letter **written** ten years ago.*     [head of clause] 
>         ii *He showed me a hurriedly **written** first draft.*          [attributive]
>
> The most elementary type of noun-modifier is an adjective (as in *a **long** letter*, *a **careless** draft*), so *written* is like an adjective in that it heads an expression with the same noun-modifying function as an adjective. The secondary feature of forming compound tenses is illustrated in [8]:
>
> [8]  i *I have **written** him a long letter.*                  [perfect] 
>         ii *The letter was **written** by her secretary.*   [passive]
>
> Note that here, certainly in the perfect use in *have written*, there is nothing adjective-like about the form. It is its use in the perfect construction that provides the basis for the 'past' component of the name, for the perfect is a kind of past tense. No element of pastness applies to the passive use, but it is predominantly the passive that is involved in noun-modifying constructions like [9], which fit the central part of the definition of participle. 'Past participle' is therefore a reasonably good name for a form with the above spread of uses. It should be emphasised, however, that the inclusion of 'past' in the name does not imply that the past participle is itself a tensed form: it is a participle which occurs in construction with the past tense auxiliary ***have***.

On p. 80:

> **The gerund-participle**
>
> This form covers the gerund and present participle of traditional grammar, which are always identical in form.
>
> ■ The traditional present participle
>
> This has uses comparable to those of the past participle:
>
> [14]  i *The train to Bath is now **approaching** Platform 3.*         [with progressive auxiliary] 
>           ii *The train **approaching** Platform 3 is the 11.10 to Bath.*                       [head of clause] 
>          iii *He threw it in the path of an **approaching** train.*                                        [attributive]
>
> Constructions [ii-iii] are those where the present participle is functionally comparable to an adjective in that it is head of an expression modifying a noun, and in [i] it combines with an auxiliary to form the progressive aspect. It is called the 'present' participle because the time associated with it is characteristically the same as that expressed or implied in the larger construction containing it (but see also §7). In [i] and [ii] the time of approaching is simultaneous with the time of speaking, but that is because the larger construction has present tense *is*. There would be no change in the form or meaning of  if we changed  to  to give *The train to Bath was approaching Platform 3.* 'Present', therefore, is to be understood in a relative rather than absolute sense: the approaching is present relative to the time given in the larger construction. Again, however, it must be emphasised that the traditional present participle is not a tensed form of the verb.

On p. 81:

> ■ The traditional gerund
>
> A gerund is traditionally understood as a word derived from a verb base which functions as or like a noun, as in:
>
> [19]  i ***Destroying*** the files was a serious mistake. 
>           ii *I regret **destroying** the files.*
>
> *Destroying the files* could be replaced by *the destruction of the files*, where *destruction* is clearly a noun. The primary difference between a gerund and a participle, therefore, is that while a participle is functionally comparable to an adjective, a gerund is functionally comparable to a noun. There is also a secondary difference: that gerunds do not combine with auxiliaries in the way that participles do.

And on pp. 82-83:

> ■ A distinction between gerund and present participle can't be sustained
>
> Historically the gerund and present participle of traditional grammar have different sources, but in Modern English the forms are identical. No verb shows any difference in form in the constructions of [14] and [19], not even ***be***. The historical difference is of no relevance to the analysis of the current inflectional system, and in accordance with 
>   principle [5i] ['An inflectional distinction is accepted between two forms only if there is at least one lexeme with a stable contrast in realisation between those two forms'] we reject an analysis that has gerund and present participle as different forms syncretised throughout the class of verbs. We have therefore just one inflectional form of the verb marked by the -*ing* suffix; we label it with the compound term 'gerund-participle' for the verb-form, as there is no reason to give priority to one or other of the traditional terms. The compound term serves also to bring out the relationship between this form and the past participle: the gerund-participle has a considerably wider distribution than the past participle (which doesn't, for example, occur in  constructions like [19i]), and yet the two forms have it in common that they head  expressions modifying nouns, as in [9] and [14ii-iii].4 This grammar also takes the view that even from the point of view of syntax (as opposed to inflection) the distinction between gerund and present participle is not viable, and we will therefore also not talk of gerund and present participle constructions: we argue the case for this position in Ch. 14, §4.3.
>
> In summary, words with a verb base and the -ing suffix fall into the following three classes:
>
> [23]  i          *She had witnessed the **killing** of the birds.*                                     [gerundial noun] 
>    
>            ii   a.   *He was expelled for **killing** the birds.*                   [gerund-participle form of verb] 
>                 b.   *They are **entertaining** the prime minister.*        [gerund-participle form of verb]
>           iii         *The show was **entertaining**.*                                                     [participial adjective]

Comment: Thanks so much linguisticturn - I'll try to explain that to the non first-language English speaker on behalf of whom I asked it.

And the observation was quite right above, I do come at it from a Latin angle - I learned more about the structure of English from Latin than I did from English in school classes.

<upvote sadly not registered - I am one of the riff-raff with reputation below 15 LOL LOL >

Comment: @Alexanderson You're welcome... (Just for future reference, in addition to upvoting and downvoting, the original asker, and only the original asker, can also 'accept' one answer by clicking the checkmark.) And good luck!

Comment: Great - that tick mark icon was certainly not obvious.

@linguisticturn : Can I ask a private question? I want to ask something on SuperUser, and something similar has probably been asked before. I don't want to get "flamed" for duplicate questions too often (though the tired duplication of the reserved question probably got a better answer here ;-P  )

I know it is a total newbie question, but can I search for similar questions from the "ask a question" screen?   As one can do on Quora.

Comment: @Alexanderson Normally, as you type the **title** of your question, the system will automatically provide a list of ***Questions that may already have your answer*** right under the box in which you are typing. I just tried it out on Super User with 'Router is intermittently down' and got six suggestions. Beyond that, of course, there's regular search and tags.

Comment: You got in first.  I might as well post what I found though :-

Comment: OK - that is resolved: 

1) SuperUser.com does bring up 6 similar questions, so that is what I was after.

2) However, I was right about the one-click search not being prominent, one has to dig a bit to find this

https://superuser.com/search

3) And there is still some "idiot-proofing" done on questions, I actually had a good laugh at this response to my question (below)

The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed.

How can I switch off the Facebook "Do you know Jessica Foster"-type popup notifications?

Comment: @Alexanderson This, unfortunately, I don't know. :)

Comment: I have the answer (to the FB question)- was just posting a bit more detail in answer to "can I search for similar questions from the "ask a question" screen"